# How to accommodate classpath user entries from Eclipse to IntelliJ in run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to migrate to `IntelliJ` from `Eclipse`. I have some `user entries` which are mentioned in the `classpath` of one of the run configurations in `Eclipse`. Exactly where/in which option should I include those entries while creating a `run configuration` in `IntelliJ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [doesn't have this feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160167) at the moment.

To include additional libraries in classpath you need to add them to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

If you need separate classpath for building and running, create a new dummy module without sources, but with libraries, then in the Run/Debug configuration specify this dummy module in the **Use classpath of module** dropdown.